# Center items inside of slick slider slide

Tags: reactjs, slick.js

I have installed slick slider and have it operational.
However I am having difficulty with centering items inside the slide[

Please refer to the attached image,
As you can see only "Dog" is centered cause I used `<p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Dog</p>` directly inside the div. This can't be my solution cause it is not text I will be displaying.

[image]

What I have attempted is to locate the slick-slide and attempt to center in the css.
However this has not worked.
Please refer to my attached code, any assistance is appreciated.

CSS

```
.slick-slide
{
    display: none;
    float: left; 

    height: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;

    textAlign: center;
    justifyContent: center;
    alignItems: center;
    
}
```

SLIDER

```
 <Slider {...settings}>
            <div>
              <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Dog</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              <p>Fish</p>
              <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://www.google.com" alt="test" />
              </a>
            </div>

            <div>
              <p>CCat</p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to your divs inside `<Slider/>` component a class(eg:`contentContainer`) and apply the next properties to it:

```
.contentContainer {
display: flex;
justify-content: center
}
```

Result:

```
<Slider {...settings}>
            <div className="contentContainer">
              <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Dog</p>
            </div>
            <div className="contentContainer">
              <p>Fish</p>
              <a href="https://www.google.com" target="_blank">
                <img src="https://www.google.com" alt="test" />
              </a>
            </div>

            <div className="contentContainer">
              <p>CCat</p>
            </div>
```